# Java. How to allow the user to skip a prompted numerical requirement using a string input?

Tags: java, skip

**Initial Question**

I am creating a program to ask the user to add students to a class. The student should have an id and could have a score (double) and a letter grade (string). In the section below, the user is prompted to input a score of a double data type. I want to allow the user to skip by inputting "s" of string data type. How can this be done given that the variable score is of a double data type?

```
        System.out.println("Kindly input Score:    (Enter s to Skip)"); 
        score = input.nextDouble();
```

Output:
Kindly input Score:    (Enter s to Skip)

**Edited Question**

Now thanks to your feedback guys, I managed to create a String variable line that reads user input, then checks whether it is "S"/"s" and parses the value into double otherwise. Now building on the question, how can I skip the prompt and proceed to the next prompt if the user decides to skip?
I have tried to use break; but it exits the entire loop . Is there a way to skip the question for score and proceed to the question for letter grade?

```
// Prompting the user for Score (Numerical Grade)

System.out.println("Kindly input Score:    (Enter s to Skip)"); 
// reading the input into the line variable of string datatype
String line = input.nextLine(); 
// checking if line =="s" or =="S" to skip, otherwise
// the value is parsed into a double
if("s".equals(line) || "S".equals(line))
{
break;  // this exists the loop. How can I just skip this requirement 
        //and go to the next prompt?
}else try
{
       score = Double.parseDouble(line);                
       System.out.println(score);
} catch( NumberFormatException nfe)
{

}
// Prompting the user for Numerical Grade
System.out.println("Kindly input Grade:    (Enter s to Skip)");
String line2 = input.nextLine();
if("s".equals(line2) || "S".equals(line2))
{
       break;  // this exists the loop. How can I just skip this 
       // requirement and go to the next prompt?
}else try
{
     score = Double.parseDouble(line2);
     System.out.println(score);
} catch( NumberFormatException nfe)
{

}
```

Comment: Use `nextLine()` instead of `nextDouble()`; check if they entered `s`, and parse it as a double otherwise.

Comment: so the datatype of score should remain as double?

Comment: Yes. But you assign the `nextLine()` to a temporary string.

Comment: Awesome. That was very helpful.

Comment: off topic comment: put the opening brace at the end of the same line, instead of a new line; it's the convention

Comment: Also, you can alway ask a new question, they are free :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validate if the user entered "s". If so, skip it, else parse a double:

```
double score;
String line = input.nextLine();
if ( "s".equals(line) ) {
   // skip
} else try {
   score  = Double.parse(line);
} catch ( NumberFormatException nfe ) { 
  // it wasn't a valid double... handle here
}
```

To skip to the next prompt just reverse the logic, instead of testing if line is 's', test if is **not** 's' to read the value

```
// psuedo code
while( true ) {
    line = "enter score or s to skip".prompt()

    if (!"s".equals(line)) { // it wasn't s, read it
       score = Double.parseDouble(line)
    } else {
       ... skip or assign a default
       score = 0.0d;
    }

    line = "enter grade or s to skip".prompt()
    if ( !"s".equals(line) ) { it wasn't s, then read
      grade = line;
    } else { 
       .. skip or put default
      grade = "A"
    }
```

}

Comment: That is very helpful!

Comment: I managed to create a String variable line that reads user input, then checks whether it is "S"/"s" and parses the value into double otherwise. Now building on the question, how can I skip the prompt and proceed to the next prompt if the user decides to skip? I have tried to use break; but it exits the entire loop . Is there a way to skip the question for score and proceed to the question for letter grade? (please check the edited question)

Answer (score 0):

You can't read a string using the `nextDouble()` method.

Instead, you could **read a string and try to parse it as double**:

```
String line = input.nextLine();

if(line.equals("s")) {
    // skip the line
} else {
    try {
        double grade = Double.parseDouble(line);

        // nice, it was a double... we can work with the grade now

    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        // neither an "s", nor a properly formatted double.
        // Time for error handling.
    }
}
```

For more info, look at the [JavaDoc for `Double.parseDouble()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)).

**Edit:** check for "s" first, parse the double after. Thanks for the hint @AndyTurner.

Comment: That was very helpful..
so, i tried the below code but i get this error: double cannot be converted to string.

System.out.println("Kindly input Score:    (Enter s to Skip)");                                 String line = input.nextLine(); 
if(line == "s" || line == "S")
 {
                                    break;
} else 
 {
                                    grade = Double.parseDouble(line);
 }

Comment: Please edit your code into your question. It is very hard to read as a comment.

Comment: Also, never compare two strings using `==`, always use `equals()`

Comment: @TimoSta exceptions are for handling *exceptional* conditions. They shouldn't be used for things that it is correct for the user to enter: check if it is `s` first, and then parse it if not.

Comment: Now thanks to your feedback guys, I managed to create a String variable line that reads user input, then checks whether it is "S"/"s" and parses the value into double otherwise. Now building on the question, how can I skip the prompt and proceed to the next prompt if the user decides to skip? I have tried to use break; but it exits the entire loop . Is there a way to skip the question for score and proceed to the question for letter grade? (please check the edited question)

Comment: @AndyTurner Agreed, the string should be checked for `s` first. But then again, even a user input of a string unequal `s` and not parseable to a double would not necessarily justify dealing with it using an Exception in my opinion. The fact that dealing with a NumberFormatException is the only practical way to check for a properly formatted double value is unfortunate.

Comment: @TimoSta but the fact is that if the user enters valid input, there should not be an exception, because that's not an exceptional case, by definition.